# what does "figures" mean at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I came across this offer:

- The daily bugle.figures i'd wind up here, but i don't have reason to go in.

what does **figures** mean at the beginning of a sentence?

in my opinion, here it should be in the meaning of the verb,but it is not clear whether it is possible to put it in the first place without the subject.
Or maybe there is a different meaning(not a verb), but I do not understand how to translate it correctly .I would be happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more correctly written "**it** figures," but the "it" is sometimes dropped in casual language.

From [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/figure):

> 12. verb
>
> If you say 'That figures' or 'It figures', you mean that the fact referred to is not surprising.
>
> [informal]
>
> - When I finished, he said, 'Yeah. That figures'. [VERB]
> - Work it out and you'll find it figures. [that/it V]

This is roughly (but not exactly) like saying "of course I'd wind up here."

Comment: thanks for the great answer

Answer (score 1):

This is American casual speech. If you figure something, you think it is true. I think the 'Daily Bugle' might be a newspaper, or a sarcastic reference to a person with lots of loudly expressed opinions.

Whe he got the gun out, I figured that he was going to shoot someone.

> Figure (verb)
>
> INFORMAL•NORTH AMERICAN
> think, consider, or expect to be the case.
> *I figured that I didn't have much of a chance*

[Figure (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/figure)